# Angularjs: Button to trigger multiple actions

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click

I’m a noob I just got my web dev certificate. I’m also new to Angularjs. I have a button that is doing several things: 
1) Receive input from site visitor, 
2)Use the input to make API calls, 
3) Make a div appear, 
4) Populate the div with data.

All this works. 
How do I make this work:  5) Scroll to the div that shows the data. I have code in the controller but I’ve done something wrong and the site does not automatically scroll to the div with the data.
I think it will be useful to be able to make button clicks trigger several events and/or changes to the dom.

I haven’t figured out how to put this in a sample site like Plunker. I can paste my controller code below.
The repo is:  https://github.com/MikeGalli/wats4030-capstone_v2
The site is:  http://thisisourgov.com/
There is one more thing it would be nice to accomplish with this button: 6) Clear visitor input.
Thanks for any insights you may have!

My code:

```
angular.module('wats4030CapstoneV2App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, current, repsearchfed, repsearch) {
    $scope.current = current.query();
    $scope.refreshCurrent = function(location) {
      $scope.current = current.query({
        location: location
      });

      //// Start Make the div visiable /////////////////
      $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
      //// End Make the div visiable /////////////////

      //// Start repsearch /////////////////
      $scope.current.$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.repsearch = repsearch.query({
          lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
          lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
        });
      });
      //// End repsearch /////////////////

      //// Start repsearchfed /////////////////
      $scope.current.$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.repsearchfed = repsearchfed.query({
          lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
          lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
        }).then(function(repdata) {
          $scope.repdata = repdata.data;
        });
      });
      //// End repsearchfed /////////////////

      //// Start Scroll to div /////////////////
      $scope.window = (function scrollWin() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 500);
        $scope.refreshCurrent.$setUntouched();
        $scope.refreshCurrent.$setPristine();
      });
      //// End Scroll to div /////////////////

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code to use `$q` service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q, `$q.all` expects an array of promises as parameter and return a promise which is resolved when each promise of the array is resolved. With this service you will not fall into a race problem with your queries.

```
angular.module('wats4030CapstoneV2App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, current, repsearchfed, repsearch) {
    $scope.current = current.query();
    $scope.refreshCurrent = function(location) {
      $scope.current = current.query({
        location: location
      });

      //// Start Make the div visiable /////////////////
      $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
      //// End Make the div visiable /////////////////

      // Start search
      $scope.current.$promise.then(function(data) {
        // Wait both queries, repsearch and repsearchfed
        $q.all([
          repsearch.query({
            lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
            lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
          }),
          repsearchfed.query({
            lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
            lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
          })
        ]).then(function (response) {
          // Search finished
          var repdata = response[0],
            repfeddata = response[1];
          $scope.repdata = repdata.data;
          $scope.repfeddata = repfeddata.data;
          // Clear input text
          $scope.location = '';
          // Scroll to section
          window.scrollTo(0, 500);
        })
      });
      //// Start repsearch /////////////////

      // $scope.current.$promise.then(function(data) {
      //   $scope.repsearch = repsearch.query({
      //     lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
      //     lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      //   });
      // });
      // //// End repsearch /////////////////

      // //// Start repsearchfed /////////////////
      // $scope.current.$promise.then(function(data) {
      //   $scope.repsearchfed = repsearchfed.query({
      //     lat: data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, //This is the Google search
      //     lng: data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      //   }).then(function(repdata) {
      //     $scope.repdata = repdata.data;
      //   });
      // });
      //// End repsearchfed /////////////////

      //// Start Scroll to div /////////////////
      // $scope.window = (function scrollWin() {
      //   window.scrollTo(0, 500);
      //   $scope.refreshCurrent.$setUntouched();
      //   $scope.refreshCurrent.$setPristine();
      // });
      //// End Scroll to div /////////////////

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rewrite the first line of the function that initiates the scroll. Basically you're waiting for the same $promise, and then applying the scrollWin function.

```
 //// Start Scroll to div /////////////////
 $scope.current.$promise.then(function scrollWin() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 1000);
   $scope.refreshCurrent.$setUntouched();
   $scope.refreshCurrent.$setPristine();
 });
 //// End Scroll to div /////////////////
```